# D7: Show node id in edit node form

Tags: drupal-7

I have been trying to display the node ID in the edit node form without any luck. Any ideas?

What I tried so far:

- Display Suite custom code (only shows on frontend)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the solution was pretty simple!

I created a view block that displays the `nid` of the current node (passed from URL).

Displaying this block in my admin theme did it for me.